# ruby on rails query on jsonb field does not work

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-postgresql, jsonb

I have a table in the PostgreSQL 9.5 with jsonb column called segmented_data and I have a record with some data in this field

```
ProjectKeyword.first
=> #<ProjectKeyword:0x007fa83a17e7f8 id: 2201, project_id: 79, keyword_id: 2201, segmented_data: {"keyword_value"=>"land for sale", "dimension_value"=>{"Property type"=>"Land"}}>
```

How I can find this record in the database by value of one of the keyw of segmented_data? 
I have tried:

```
ProjectKeyword.where("segmented_data ->> 'keyword_value' = 'land for sale'").first
=> nil

 ProjectKeyword.where('segmented_data @> ?',  {keyword_value: 'land for sale'}.to_json).first
=> nil

ProjectKeyword.where('segmented_data @> ? ', '{"keyword_value":"land for sale"}' ).first
=> nil
```

What am I doing wrong in these queryes?

**EDITED**

My Model

```
class ProjectKeyword < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :segmented_data, JSON
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :keyword
  has_many :project_keyword_dimensions
  has_many :dimensions, through: :project_keyword_dimensions

  validates :project_id, :keyword_id, presence: true
end
```

Migration

```
class AddSegemtnedDataToProjectKeywords < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :project_keywords, :segmented_data, :jsonb, default: '{}'
    add_index  :project_keywords, :segmented_data, using: :gin
  end
end
```

**EDITED**

I think I found a possible reason of this problem
My db schema still was not in sql format and I added this line

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

into application.rb file

But now if i running command

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
```

I get this error

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:structure:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Invoke db:load_config
** Execute db:structure:dump
I, [2016-06-21T08:09:14.083751 #51538]  INFO -- : [Rollbar] Scheduling item
I, [2016-06-21T08:09:14.102300 #51538]  INFO -- : [Rollbar] Details: https://rollbar.com/instance/uuid?uuid=fgfffgf (only available if report was successful)
rake aborted!
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:99:in `system'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:99:in `run_cmd'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:64:in `structure_dump'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:207:in `structure_dump'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:292:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:67:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:59:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:24:in `run'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:304:in `exec'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:27:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:98:in `with_friendly_errors'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:19:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/atrthur/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:structure:dump
```

What is wrong with it? How to fix it?

Comment: is the raw SQL working?

Comment: How can I check it?  I have in my 'initializers/active_record.rb' this line `Rails.application.config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
` if you mean this?

Comment: can you try?   ProjectKeyword.where('segmented_data @> ? ',  '{"keyword_value":"land for sale"}'     ).first   try a .to_sql also to get the sql

Comment: Weird for me the second query just work. `CallRecord.where('parsed_json @> ?',{"CRN" => "8000015838"}.to_json)` this is how my data is structured.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the datatype of the `segmented_data` JSON/JSONB

Comment: Also, I feel this form of query will not work `"segmented_data ->> 'keyword_value' = 'land for sale'"` because if you check the json doc [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) the `->>` return the output as `text`.`where` need a predicate i.e a `boolean` output.

Comment: You can use that in `select` though. `Project.select("segemented ->> 'keyword'").where(....) `

Comment: I have tried `ProjectKeyword.where('segmented_data @> ? ', '{"keyword_value":"land for sale"}' ).first` , it also does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this problem was to remove this line

```
serialize :segmented_data, JSON
```

from model `ProjectKeyword`

After this line was removed all queries started to work, only the problem now that the default value of `: segmented_data` is not the hash anymore, it became a string `'{}'`
So before you update data in this field I have to assign hash value to this field

```
project_keyword.segmented_data = {}
project_keyword.save!
```